# Understanding a MySQL table's maximum column width

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to understand how MySQL 8.0 row width works, and some parts are quite confusing.  The easiest way to explain my challenge is to show it in code.  Please don't focus on the fact that using so many columns could be a bad db design; I know that, this is just to help illustrate my confusion.

If I create a table with 186 columns using the below statement, the maximum varchar length I can use is 116.  Using utf8, that has an apparent length of 64,728 bytes.  (186 columns x 116 char/col x 3 byte/char).  And it works for me.

```
create table RowTest(Row1 varchar(116),Row2 varchar(116),Row3 varchar(116),Row4 varchar(116),Row5 varchar(116),Row6 varchar(116),Row7 varchar(116),Row8 varchar(116),Row9 varchar(116),Row10 varchar(116),Row11 varchar(116),Row12 varchar(116),Row13 varchar(116),Row14 varchar(116),Row15 varchar(116),Row16 varchar(116),Row17 varchar(116),Row18 varchar(116),Row19 varchar(116),Row20 varchar(116),Row21 varchar(116),Row22 varchar(116),Row23 varchar(116),Row24 varchar(116),Row25 varchar(116),Row26 varchar(116),Row27 varchar(116),Row28 varchar(116),Row29 varchar(116),Row30 varchar(116),Row31 varchar(116),Row32 varchar(116),Row33 varchar(116),Row34 varchar(116),Row35 varchar(116),Row36 varchar(116),Row37 varchar(116),Row38 varchar(116),Row39 varchar(116),Row40 varchar(116),Row41 varchar(116),Row42 varchar(116),Row43 varchar(116),
Row44 varchar(116),Row45 varchar(116),Row46 varchar(116),Row47 varchar(116),Row48 varchar(116),Row49 varchar(116),Row50 varchar(116),Row51 varchar(116),Row52 varchar(116),Row53 varchar(116),Row54 varchar(116),Row55 varchar(116),Row56 varchar(116),Row57 varchar(116),Row58 varchar(116),Row59 varchar(116),Row60 varchar(116),Row61 varchar(116),Row62 varchar(116),Row63 varchar(116),Row64 varchar(116),Row65 varchar(116),Row66 varchar(116),Row67 varchar(116),Row68 varchar(116),Row69 varchar(116),Row70 varchar(116),Row71 varchar(116),Row72 varchar(116),Row73 varchar(116),Row74 varchar(116),Row75 varchar(116),Row76 varchar(116),Row77 varchar(116),Row78 varchar(116),Row79 varchar(116),Row80 varchar(116),Row81 varchar(116),Row82 varchar(116),Row83 varchar(116),Row84 varchar(116),Row85 varchar(116),Row86 varchar(116),Row87 varchar(116),
Row88 varchar(116),Row89 varchar(116),Row90 varchar(116),Row91 varchar(116),Row92 varchar(116),Row93 varchar(116),Row94 varchar(116),Row95 varchar(116),Row96 varchar(116),Row97 varchar(116),Row98 varchar(116),Row99 varchar(116),Row100 varchar(116),Row101 varchar(116),Row102 varchar(116),Row103 varchar(116),Row104 varchar(116),Row105 varchar(116),Row106 varchar(116),Row107 varchar(116),Row108 varchar(116),Row109 varchar(116),Row110 varchar(116),Row111 varchar(116),Row112 varchar(116),Row113 varchar(116),Row114 varchar(116),Row115 varchar(116),Row116 varchar(116),Row117 varchar(116),Row118 varchar(116),Row119 varchar(116),Row120 varchar(116),Row121 varchar(116),Row122 varchar(116),Row123 varchar(116),Row124 varchar(116),Row125 varchar(116),Row126 varchar(116),Row127 varchar(116),Row128 varchar(116),Row129 varchar(116),Row130 varchar(116),Row131 varchar(116),
Row132 varchar(116),Row133 varchar(116),Row134 varchar(116),Row135 varchar(116),Row136 varchar(116),Row137 varchar(116),Row138 varchar(116),Row139 varchar(116),Row140 varchar(116),Row141 varchar(116),Row142 varchar(116),Row143 varchar(116),Row144 varchar(116),Row145 varchar(116),Row146 varchar(116),Row147 varchar(116),Row148 varchar(116),Row149 varchar(116),Row150 varchar(116),Row151 varchar(116),Row152 varchar(116),Row153 varchar(116),Row154 varchar(116),Row155 varchar(116),Row156 varchar(116),Row157 varchar(116),Row158 varchar(116),Row159 varchar(116),Row160 varchar(116),Row161 varchar(116),Row162 varchar(116),Row163 varchar(116),Row164 varchar(116),Row165 varchar(116),Row166 varchar(116),Row167 varchar(116),Row168 varchar(116),Row169 varchar(116),Row170 varchar(116),Row171 varchar(116),Row172 varchar(116),Row173 varchar(116),Row174 varchar(116),
Row175 varchar(116),Row176 varchar(116),Row177 varchar(116),Row178 varchar(116),Row179 varchar(116),Row180 varchar(116),Row181 varchar(116),Row182 varchar(116),Row183 varchar(116),Row184 varchar(116),Row185 varchar(116),Row186 varchar(116)) 
engine = innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 row_format = compressed;
```

If I increase each row above to varchar(117), I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1118. Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535.
```

That makes sense, because that puts us above the 65,535 boundary.  (Assuming there is some amount of hidden consumption.)

But if I create a table with ONE additional column (187 columns), the maximum varchar length I can use now drops from 116 to 13 (!).  And if I try to increase it to varchar(14), I get a completely different error.

```
Error Code: 1118. Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

It seems like going from 186 columns to 187 columns has somehow kicked me into a different boundary that is much lower.

I do know that MySQL has multiple boundaries, but I'm not sure why adding a single column would reduce the table's maximum width from 65k to 8126.  After all, with one less column, the table is much wider.

Any ideas how to understand what's going on behind the scenes?  Or is there anything published that explains exactly how to calculate table width against each of the boundaries in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another thing to consider: This page (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html) states that when a row is too long, the longest columns are chosen for off-page storage until the clustered index record fits on the B-tree page.  I don't think this can increase the table width past 65,545, but shouldn't it enable 187 columns of varchar(14)?

Comment: `Please don't focus on the fact that using so many columns could be a bad db design` - it's the Streisand effect

Comment: Varchar(14) columns are definitely stored all within the row, pushing the row length over innodb's maximum of 8126.

Comment: But innodb's maximum is 65,535 UNTIL I get to 187 columns.  Then it drops to 8126.  I'm confused by why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies on the mysql manual page you linked in your comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html

Your innodb table uses compressed row format, which has the same storage characteristics as the dynamic row format.

One of the characteristics of the dynamic row format is:

> Whether columns are stored off-page depends on the page size and the total size of the row. When a row is too long, the longest columns are chosen for off-page storage until the clustered index record fits on the B-tree page. TEXT and BLOB columns that are less than or equal to 40 bytes are stored in line.

The `varchar(116)` fields are probably considered too long and therefore are stored in the overflow pages. Therefore, only a 20 byte pointer to the overflow page is stored within the row itself and 186×20 bytes is the size that counts toward the innodb limit of 8126 bytes per row. However, their full size counts towards the mysql limit of 65535 bytes.

But when you change the field types to `varchar(13)` or `varchar(14)`, that's probably considered as short (40 byte limit applies to text and blob types only), therefore are stored within the row, not in the overflow pages. Therefore, their entire length counts toward the innodb limit of 8126 bytes. The row contains additional data as well.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear... When I add the extra column, using varchar(116) makes the table too long, which is expected, but so does varchar(115) and varchar(114) and so on, all the way down to varchar(14).  Once I get to 187 columns, the max varchar length that still works is reduced all the way to 13.  The table goes from having a max width of 65,535 to 1826.  What I'm asking is, why the drastic drop in maximum table width?

Comment: 65536 is mysql's absolute limit on row sizes. However, storage engines can have different limitations. Innodb has a concept of core index pages and overflow pages. The mysql limit applies to the combined index and overflow page length. But innodb has a separate limit on the core index page size. The short columns are stored fully in the core index page, while longer ones are stored in the overflow page. By reducing the field length you bump into innodb limit as opposed to the mysql limit.